# Should Bower automatically include library js and css files so they don't need to be listed in the index.html

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, bower

It is possible I am misunderstanding how Bower is used. I have an ionic project with a number of Bower added libraries in the www/lib folder. I am having to explicitly include the js files in my index.html.

I thought having bower files was supposed to do this automatically for you. Is this not the case?

Comment: is not. bower downloads for you the libs, does not decide where you need it.

Comment: That fits in with my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nop, bower is a dependency library.

The library only reads your dependencies, looks for the best version (given your semver configuration in bower.json and dependencies configuration), and download in your respective root folder or bower_components (by default).

The approach that your are looking could be done by libraries like [Wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) that reads your dependencies tree and inserts all the libraries in the file that you say. And could be used with grunt or gulp build process.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly I misunderstood. That makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Thanks for Wiredep link, haven't come across it before.